# can't open database exception in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i'm having problem understanding what is the error with opening the database since my program works fine but it displays this error.can anyone help me in understanding this.

this is how i check the database exists in the main

```
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("Event.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        checkDB.close();

    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {
        eventDB = new DatabaseEvent(this);
    }
    return checkDB != null;
}
```

i'm getting this error i don't know how to fix?

```
E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database 'MyACtion.db'.
                                                                        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
```

Comment: You do not define the database name in database helper class

Comment: no i do from the constants interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onCreate method of DatabaseEvent class change the SQL from:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE... ;");
```

to

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE... "); // NO SEMI-COLON
```

also, in your checkDataBase method, you're not opening the same database you are creating in DatabaseEvent.  Instead call:

```
DatabaseEvent db = new DatabaseEvent(context);
db.getReadableDatabase();
```

Comment: i think the method for getAllData() returns null even after doing this

Comment: does return null  instead of the values?